# PHP Array Not Working in Function

Tags: php, arrays, user-defined-functions

I'm currently experimenting with arrays in PHP, and I created a fake environment where a team's information will be displayed.

```
    $t1 = array (
            "basicInfo" => array (
                "The Sineps",
                "December 25, 2010",
                "lemonpole"
            ),
            "overallRecord" => array (0, 0, 0, 0),
            "overallSeasons" => array (
                1 => array (14, 0, 0),
                2 => array (9, 5, 2),
                3 => array (12, 4, 0),
                4 => array (3, 11, 2)
            ),
            "games" => array (
                "<img src=\"images/cs.gif\" alt=\"Counter-Strike\" />",
                "<img src=\"images/cs.gif\" alt=\"Counter-Strike\" />",
                "<img src=\"images/cs.gif\" alt=\"Counter-Strike\" />",
                "<img src=\"images/cs.gif\" alt=\"Counter-Strike\" />"
            ),
            "seasonHistory" => array (
                "Season I",
                "Season II",
                "Season III",
                "Season IV"
            ),
            "divisions" => array (
                "Open",
                "Main",
                "Main",
                "Invite"
            )
        );
// Displays the seasons the team has been in along
    // with the record of each season.
    function seasonHistory() {
        // Make array variable local-scope.
        global $t1;

        // Count the number of seasons.
        $numrows = count($t1["seasonHistory"]);

        // Loop through all the variables until
        // it reaches the last entry made and display
        // each item seperately.
        for($v = 0; $v <= $numrows; $v++) {
            // Echo each season.
            echo "<tr><td>{$t1["games"][$v]}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$t1["seasonHistory"][$v]}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$t1["divisions"][$v]}</td></tr>";
        }
    }
```

I have tested several possible problems out and after narrowing them down I have come down to one conclusion and that is **my function is not connecting to the array for some reason**. I don't know what else to do because I thought making the array global would fix that problem.

What works:

1. I can echo **$t1["games"][0]** on the page I need it to display and it gives me the content.
2. I tried echo **$t1["games"][0]** INSIDE the function and then calling the function and it doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extract($t1);
```

Try this function instead of global.

Better idea is to pass array as argument...

```
function seasonHistory($array){

$t1 = $array;

//your function
}
```

Comment: nope :( it gives me an error saying that the parameter expects an array. I'm guessing that error is because my function isn't connecting to the array...

Comment: YEP :D that worked. I don't understand why all of a sudden it doesn't work if I have been experimenting with arrays and simply making the array global always worked..

Comment: Try to pass array as argument, that should by all means work. Quite odd that global and extract don't work. Is this original code?

Comment: Yea I made the array myself and the function as well. It has worked before in another environment.. but the file structure was different; then I was not using includes and switches. Could it be that?

Comment: Ok, that's it :) Generally using global and extract in this manner is not good, better solution is to pass variable/array like function argument. Accept as correct answer, please.

Comment: Yea the page I'm calling the function on an include from another page... and I planned on accepting just waiting for the 8min to be up :)

Comment: Just pass array as argument, to avoid this problems in general. That way you also create reusable function (doesn't depend on array name).

Answer (score 3):

This can happen if you define your `$t1` not in the global scope. Try explicitly putting it into globals, by doing `$GLOBALS['t1'] = $t1;` right after you define your variable.